# installing bumblebee on 13.10 for my 635M nvidia / 4000M intel is breaking X and putting me in low graphics hell. Please help

Tags: nvidia, intel, bumblebee

Today's date is Dec 2, 2013

I have an Asus R500VJ (aka K55VJ) - with an ivybridge 4000M intel and a Nvidia 635M. lately every time I use the installation method prescribed on the official bumblebee "ask" it breaks my X configuration and puts me in low graphics hell. I'm some what savvy with Linux, but only enough to damage my install. I've got this to work in the past but haven't had the time to do the reading.

LINKS:

https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/stable
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#A.22Cannot_access_secondary_GPU.22_error

Oddly enough I've got this to work in the past but haven't had the time. This is annoying.... please help. I'm probably forgetting to modify something. I've been reading, but I can't get any alone time to work though these issues. GF is super prego and won't stop interrupting everything I do.

A helpful answer would really remove a lot of my stress.

here is what I've ran in the past

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
```

Also for some reason I'm always missing glxgears and glxspheres.... they just seems not to be there and I have a feeling installing mesa-utils is messing with steam and causing it to throw an error. but again that only installs gears and not spheres.

cheers,
J

Answer (score 0):

I have now nearly the same issue.

Please check your Xorg.0.log

if you see something like

```
[    10.109] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[    10.109] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[    10.109] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
```

Then remooving Bumblebee maybe the way to solve the problem. I will try it myself this evening.

Taken from here: [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399153/after-apt-get-upgrade-system-always-boot-to-low-graphics-mode)

Comment: Finally worked for me.